# Localhost:3000 We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, localhost

I just deployed my rails website to Heroku and it worked well. Then now the problem is I can't open my website on localhost:3000. It showed

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

This is the logs i got from $rails console logs, I don't know what to do and scare will make it worst. Any help is appreciated!

```
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:236:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'log
s' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:217:in `resolve_connection'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:138:in `resolve'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:168:in `spec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:53:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `block in run_console_blocks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:247:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:247:in `each_registered_block'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `run_console_blocks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:463:in `block in run_console_blocks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:463:in `run_console_blocks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:442:in `load_console'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:34:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: In rails console.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not configured the database.

**database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)**

Please configure it in the `database.yml` file. [Cofiguring a database - Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)